# SSIS change from a Store procedure to a Web Service call

Tags: ssis

I have been told to change my SSIS package from a Stored procedure call to a Web service call.  The Stored procedure was picking up a list of files that my SSIS package needs to process.  The call returns file name and the complete path to the file, so multiple rows and multiple columns coming back.  So I am running a foreach loop on the object variable(the return from the stored procedure) to process the files.

I put the web service call into my package and set the output to a string variable.  I then set up a data flow as I was going to try a XML Source with a recordset Destination to put the xml into a object variable to allow my foreach loop to process as it currently stands.

The problem is the XSD definition of the XML.  I do not have one.

Is there a way to get the XSD definition or is there a better way to get the results I am after?

Comment: So who wrote the web service providing the XML to you? Normally whoever builds the web service provides the WSD, often against a URL (as required by the SSIS task and any other web service consumer). If your source XML is simple you should be able to manualy construct the WSD document and save it as a static document on a web server somewhere.

Comment: Failing that you can do it all in script without a WSD (but you still need to know the logic to shred the XML). Here is an example of how to consume a web service from a script task: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farukcelik/archive/2009/07/17/ssis-consuming-a-web-service-without-using-web-service-task-and-http-connection-manager-within-script-task.aspx and here is an example of how to populate a recordset object (to be subsequently used in a for each loop) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9c04e31c-5b7c-4281-b35a-d2b3bb9bd33c/prepopulate-an-object-variable-via-script-task